Automatic Alignment of Cell Contents in Table
First: I've split up my question(s) from Cleaning up code and here is one of the bullets, with the code somewhat reduced.
Consider
\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt
]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  NFSSFamily     = tgp,
  Extension      = .otf,
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  Ligatures      = {
    TeX,
    CommonOff
  }
]{texgyrepagella}
\usepackage[
  math-style = TeX
]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\setmathfont[
  version  = bold,
  FakeBold = 4
]{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\DeclareSymbolFont{textdigits}{TU}{tgp}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{textdigits}{bold}{TU}{tgp}{b}{n}
\Umathcode`0="7 \symtextdigits `0
\Umathcode`1="7 \symtextdigits `1
\Umathcode`2="7 \symtextdigits `2
\Umathcode`3="7 \symtextdigits `3
\Umathcode`4="7 \symtextdigits `4
\Umathcode`5="7 \symtextdigits `5
\Umathcode`6="7 \symtextdigits `6
\Umathcode`7="7 \symtextdigits `7
\Umathcode`8="7 \symtextdigits `8
\Umathcode`9="7 \symtextdigits `9
\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\psset{
  dimen = m,
  PointSymbol = none,
  PointName = none,
  MarkAngleRadius = 0.25,
  RightAngleSize = 0.2,
  LabelSep = -0.3
}

\def\mlr{1}
\newcommand*\saenk[1]{\raisebox{\fpeval{-5/9*\mlr}ex}{#1}}
\newcommand*\nyLinje[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{
    |p{4.95cm}|
     >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4.95cm}|
     >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4.95cm}|
  }
   \hline
      \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{\fpeval{-1.2*\mlr}ex}{Du kender \dots}}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\saenk{Du kan beregne \dots}} \\[\mlr ex]
   \cline{2-3}
    
    & \saenk{sider}
    & \saenk{vinkler} \\[\mlr ex]
   \hline
      Siderne~$a$ og~$b$\hspace*{2em}%
      \raisebox{\fpeval{-4.5*\mlr}ex}{%
      \begin{pspicture}(0,-0.38)(1.33,1.5)
       \small
        \pstGeonode(0,0){A}(1,1.5){B}(1,0){C}
        \pspolygon(A)(B)(C)
        \pstRightAngle{B}{C}{A}
        \uput{0.1}[315](C){$C$}
       {\psset{
          linestyle = none
        }
        \pcline[offset = 6pt](B)(C)
        \ncput{$a$}
        \pcline[offset = 7pt](C)(A)
        \ncput{$b$}}
      \end{pspicture}}
    & $c = \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$
    & \parbox{4cm}{\vspace*{-1ex}\begin{align*}
        A &= \tan^{-1}{\mkern -7mu}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right){\mkern -7mu}\\
        B &= \tan^{-1}{\mkern -7mu}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right){\mkern -7mu}
% \\       &= \ang{90} - A
      \end{align*}\vspace*{-1ex}} \\[\mlr ex]
   \hline
      Siderne~$a$ og~$c$\hspace*{2.06em}%
      \raisebox{\fpeval{-4.5*\mlr}ex}{%
      \begin{pspicture}(0,-0.35)(1.33,1.5)
       \small
        \pstGeonode(0,0){A}(1,1.5){B}(1,0){C}
        \pspolygon(A)(B)(C)
        \pstRightAngle{B}{C}{A}
        \uput{0.1}[315](C){$C$}
       {\psset{
          linestyle = none
        }
        \pcline[offset = 6pt](B)(C)
        \ncput{$a$}
        \pcline[offset = 6pt](A)(B)
        \ncput{$c$}}
      \end{pspicture}}
    & $b = \sqrt{c^{2} - a^{2}}$
    & \parbox{4cm}{\begin{align*}
        A &= \sin^{-1}{\mkern -7mu}\left(\frac{a}{c}\right){\mkern -7mu}\\
        B &= \cos^{-1}{\mkern -7mu}\left(\frac{a}{c}\right){\mkern -7mu}
% \\       &= \ang{90} - A
      \end{align*}} \\[\mlr ex]
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}

Question
How do I automatically left-align the text in the first column and right-align the drawings? (All the manually added space is really ugly.)

If you want to automatically left align the text while right align the drawings in the first column, then I would suggest to divide them into two columns. In this way the alignment control becomes quite easy.
Since you also want all the rows except the header to have the same height, this can be achieved by the row option from the tabularray package (in the following I set row{3-Z}={3cm} where Z represents for the last row).
Code:
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm,showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\psset{
  dimen = m,
  PointSymbol = none,
  PointName = none,
  MarkAngleRadius = 0.25,
  RightAngleSize = 0.2,
  LabelSep = -0.3
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={|Q[l,3cm]Q[r,1.5cm]|Q[c,4cm]|Q[c,5cm]|},
  row{1-2}={m,cyan6},
  row{3-Z}={m,3cm},hlines}
  \SetCell[r=2,c=2]{c} Du kender \dots & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Du kan beregne \dots & \\
   & & sider & vinkler \\
   Siderne $a$ og $b$ &
    \parbox{2cm}{\begin{pspicture}(0,-0.38)(1.33,1.5)
      \small
      \pstGeonode(0,0){A}(1,1.5){B}(1,0){C}
      \pspolygon(A)(B)(C)
      \pstRightAngle{B}{C}{A}
      \uput{0.1}[315](C){$C$}
      {\psset{
        linestyle = none
      }
      \pcline[offset = 6pt](B)(C)
      \ncput{$a$}
      \pcline[offset = 7pt](C)(A)
      \ncput{$b$}}
    \end{pspicture}} & 
    $c = \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$
    & $\begin{array}{l}
        A = \tan^{-1}{\mkern -7mu}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right){\mkern -7mu}\\
        B = \tan^{-1}{\mkern -7mu}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right){\mkern -7mu}
      \end{array}$ \\
  Siderne $a$ og $c$ &
    \parbox{2cm}{\begin{pspicture}(0,-0.35)(1.33,1.5)
      \small
      \pstGeonode(0,0){A}(1,1.5){B}(1,0){C}
      \pspolygon(A)(B)(C)
      \pstRightAngle{B}{C}{A}
      \uput{0.1}[315](C){$C$}
      {\psset{
        linestyle = none
      }
      \pcline[offset = 6pt](B)(C)
      \ncput{$a$}
      \pcline[offset = 6pt](A)(B)
      \ncput{$c$}}
    \end{pspicture}} & $b = \sqrt{c^{2} - a^{2}}$ &
     $\begin{array}{l}
      A = \sin^{-1}{\mkern -7mu}\left(\frac{a}{c}\right){\mkern -7mu}\\
      B = \cos^{-1}{\mkern -7mu}\left(\frac{a}{c}\right){\mkern -7mu}
     \end{array}$ \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


